# How to export a JSON row to data.frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to export a JSON value inside a row value to a new column in my data.set.

My current data.set:

```
   a  b  c
------------------- 
1 20 10 {d:10, e:6} 
2 25 15 {d:30, f:7}
3 40 20 {d:5}

to

   a  b  c  d  e  f
------------------- 
1 20 10  0 10  6  0
2 25 15  0 30  0  7
3 40 20  0  5  0  0
```

Comment: Can't package `rjson` be used to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `rjson` and `plyr` :

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(20,25,40),
                b=c(10,15,20),
                c=c('{"d":10, "e":6}','{"d":30, "f":7}','{"d":5}'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(rjson)
library(plyr)

tmp <- lapply(d$c, fromJSON)
tmp <- ldply(lapply(tmp, as.data.frame), I)
tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
cbind(d, tmp)
```

Which gives :

```
   a  b               c  d e f
1 20 10 {"d":10, "e":6} 10 6 0
2 25 15 {"d":30, "f":7} 30 0 7
3 40 20         {"d":5}  5 0 0
```

Note that you must use `plyr` here and not `dplyr`, as the `ldply` function is not available in the latter.